# Error While trying to migrate to wicket 6

Tags: java, maven, wicket-6

I've tried to migrate from wicket 1.4 to wicket 6, but I got to this error:

> Failed to execute goal on project WicketExamples: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.core:WicketExamples:war:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.wicket:wicket:jar:6.12.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

here is my dependencies on pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>6.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>6.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Are there any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first dependency should be wicket-core not wicket:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The latest version of wicket is 6.13.0